# sqlalchemy model : how to insert autoincrement primary id value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

model class:

```
class ActivityLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "activity_log"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(200), nullable=False, index=True)
    request_url = Column(String(200), nullable=False, unique=False, index=False)
    execution_timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    response_type = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=False, index=False)
    input_params = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=False, index=False)
```

create table query:

```
create table activity_log 
(id int NOT NULL, 
 username varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
 request_url varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
 execution_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL, 
 response_type varchar(100), 
 input_params varchar(100), 
 constraint activity_log_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

inserting data in table:

```
data_file = models.ActivityLog(username=username,
                           request_url=request_url,
                           execution_timestamp=execution_timestamp,
                           response_type=str(type(audio_wav)),
                           input_params=utterance_id)
```

Error in activity_log: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")

Comment: Did you change the code after creating the tables? I.e. are you sure your table structure is in sync with your models? SQLAlchemy won't automagically update the table structure stored in your database if you change your models, either remove the tables and run `create_all` again, or use a migration library like alembic to maintain the state of the database over time (usually more relevant as your project has started to be used)

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh recreating the table helped...difference was in line autoincrement=True

Comment: updated table creation sql to this:                                                                       create table activity_log 
(id int NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, 
 username varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
 request_url varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
 execution_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL, 
 response_type varchar(100), 
 input_params varchar(100), 
 constraint activity_log_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));